# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () in blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm learning blazor web assembly and I was trying to build an authentication (JWt) project with blazor but I get in the client side an error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (): api/Auth/login:1
```

I have tested the API and it is connected to a database and works perfectly I made a CustomAuthenticationStateProvider

AuthController: Login endpoint:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromQuery] Login model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);


            var result = await _authService.LoginAsync(model);

            if (!result.ISAuthenticated)
                return BadRequest(result.Message);

            

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

CustomAuthenticationStateProvider:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider: AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage;
        private ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

        public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(ISessionStorageService sessionStorage)
        {
            _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var userSession = await _sessionStorage.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
                if (userSession == null)
                    return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                }, "JwtAuth"));

                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal));
            }
            catch
            {
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
            }
        }

        public async Task UpdateAuthenticationState(UserSession? userSession)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

            if (userSession != null)
            {
                claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userSession.UserName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userSession.Role)
                }));
                userSession.ExpiryTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(userSession.ExpiresIn);
                await _sessionStorage.SaveItemEncryptedAsync("UserSession", userSession);
            }
            else
            {
                claimsPrincipal = _anonymous;
                await _sessionStorage.RemoveItemAsync("UserSession");
            }

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(claimsPrincipal)));
        }

        public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var userSession = await _sessionStorage.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<UserSession>("UserSession");
                if (userSession != null && DateTime.Now < userSession.ExpiryTimeStamp)
                    result = userSession.Token;
            }
            catch { }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

loginPage:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 pt-4 pb-4 border">
        <div class="mb-3 text-center">
            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>User Name</label>
            <input @bind="loginRequest.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input @bind="loginRequest.Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 d-grid gap-2">
            <button @onclick="Authenticate" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private Login loginRequest = new Login();

    private async Task Authenticate()
    {
        var loginResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<Login>("/api/Auth/login", loginRequest);

        if (loginResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var userSession = await loginResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<UserSession>();
            var customAuthStateProvider = (CustomAuthenticationStateProvider)authStateProvider;
            await customAuthStateProvider.UpdateAuthenticationState(userSession);
            navManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
        }
        else if (loginResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            await js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Invalid User Name or Password");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **AuthController**, the **LoginAsync** action method expects **Login** model from query parameters (using [FromQuery] indicates it's expecting from query param), but you're sending **Login** model in the HTTP request body.

change the code as follows:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody] Login model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);


            var result = await _authService.LoginAsync(model);

            if (!result.ISAuthenticated)
                return BadRequest(result.Message);

            

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

**[FromBody]** attribute indicates the data will be received from the request body.

also, make sure you're sending valid data from the client end.